# Passing a third-party api client object between tasks in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have 2 tasks in my DAG, the first one creates an API client object based on the API key provided, and the second uses this client object to make other API calls.

I'm using Airflow 2.1.2, and I'm trying out the taskflow API.

I tried to do something like what is described [here](https://medium.com/apache-airflow/airflow-2-0-dag-authoring-redesigned-651edc397178). I got the datatype `abc_library.api.ABC_library` by checking `type(api_client)`.

```
from abc_library import ABC_library 

(In functions.py)
@task(task_id="check_connection")
def check_connection() -> abc_library.api.ABC_library:
    api_client = ABC_library(api_key="abcabcabcabc")
    return api_client

@task(task_id="download_data")
def download(api_client: abc_library.api.ABC_library):
    api_client.download()

(In my_dag.py)
with DAG('abc_download', catchup=False, default_args=default_args) as dag:
    api_client = check_connection() 
    download_data(api_client)
```

I tested the dag using the `airflow tasks test` command. The output I got was simply `airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: abc_download. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.`

When I checked `my_dag.py.log`, I see the error message

```
def check_connection() -> abc_library.api.ABC_library:
NameError: name 'abc_library' is not defined
```

But if I ran the `check_connection` task without trying to pass the API client object, it runs successfully, i.e. there shouldn't be a problem with importing the library because it was called and successfully returned `api_client`. I'm not sure if I'm using the right syntax here. Is there another way to pass the API client object between tasks? Is it more complicated because it's not technically data (e.g. int, dataframes, etc)?